# AlertDialog is opened again

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

There is a fragment. When I press button on this fragment alert dialog is shown. This dialog is dissmissed after clicking on OK button. If I go to next fragment from current fragment and then come back - previous fragment is appeared with opened alert dialog. I use Cicerone for navigating. Maybe somebody faced with this problem?

```
// for navigating
router.navigateTo(screenKey);


// show dialog
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
        .setCancelable(true)
        .create();
alert.show();


// in my second fragment
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    showBackButton();
}


// in my main activity
@Override
public void showBackButton() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(Utils.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
        onBackPressed();
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    hideKeyboard();
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        hideDrawerLayout();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you calling show dialog exactly ? Cause right now it seems block less.

Comment: You should replace alert dialog code to other method to prevent invoking onresume

Comment: @ADM well, this code is in one of the methods of BaseActivity (MainActivity extends BaseActivity).

Comment: It seems that, dialog is shown as possibility of called alert.show() in inappropriate way in any of lifecycle methods. find out that cause, Since the code you have given, it is not traceable for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have find a solution. Point is that Moxy framework is used in my project and I didn't set right state strategy type in my views. Now I use SkipStrategy to not pile up commands in the queue. Sorry for your time I spent :)

Comment: There is one problem: if you just recreate activity (rotate device for example), then you won't show this AlertDialog. If you want, you are able to do something like [there](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/blob/master/sample-github/src/main/java/com/arellomobile/mvp/sample/github/ui/activities/SignInActivity.java#L79). See what I do with `mErrorDialog`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    dialog.close()
}
```

This will do the trick, in your parent activity where you are creating your dialog add this. Try to comment and uncomment super.onResume(); while testing.

Comment: cancel() is same as that of dismiss(), This is essentially the same as calling dismiss(), but it will also call your DialogInterface.OnCancelListener (if registered).

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan Unfortunately, this code not help me. Sangeet is right.

Comment: Is this your complete code buddy ? where you are calling these can you show us activity please

Comment: I edited the answer please check it, It will do the job :) and let me know if it works

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan Maybe you mean dialog.dismiss()? it seems like a crutch a bit, cause this solution does not fix the problem, only hide a consequences, but for now I use this solution. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yea I told you already its just a hack .. mark my answer as answer if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

What i got that You are navigating in first line and in next step you are showing the Dialog. These will execute one after another. I Hope you got my point . Do it as below :

```
 AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, which) ->
                dialog.dismiss()// Optinal
                router.navigateTo(screenKey);
        )
        .setCancelable(true)
        .create();
alert.show();
```

And no need to dismiss the dialog, cause its the default behavior of AlertDialog.Let me know its solved your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think you did not understand me. I go to second fragment not from dialog. I close dialog and click on some element on first fragment and its click handler navigates me to another fragment. And then, when I come back from second fragment - first fragment appears with opened dialog.